# Creating a Registry Key in vb.net 2010 'NullReferenceException was unhandled'

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, registrykey

I have a problem with creating a Registry Key...

This is my code :

```
   Dim KeyName As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
   Dim Value As String = Application.ExecutablePath
   My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(KeyName, True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Value)
```

And this is my problem :

[image]

Some help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your key name includes "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\". `My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser` already takes you to HKEY_CURRENT_USER so you don't need that as part of the key name. You first statement should be

```
Dim KeyName As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
```

Comment: Oh yes, i missed it,Thanks :) [Blackwood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4424957/blackwood)